# How does scala sandboxing work

Tags: security, scala, scripting

I've been looking at this:

http://calumleslie.blogspot.com/2008/06/simple-jvm-sandboxing.html

regarding sandboxing the JVM. However, that was written three (four?) years ago now, and is for Java. I haven't managed to find anything more recent or specific.

I know I could probably do the same thing for Scala, but I was wondering if Scala had any inbuilt sandboxing capabilities? The use case is to do scripting and configuration in Scala (like how Lift does it) while still maintaining security (i.e. preventing config.scala opening network sockets or reading from the hard disk). Does anyone have any experience doing this?

Comment: Note that the blog post to which you are linking has a section on doing this from Scala. Now if you are asking whether the Scala library implements some dedicated mechanism, then the answer is no.

Comment: You should know that the security API is build into the JVM, not limited to java. So Everything that is true for Java in security management is also true for Scala.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the same mechanism as in Java: install a [SecurityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html) . The default ClassLoader will give loaded code a "read" FilePermission for its own classpath and an "exitVM" RuntimePermission; other actions require [permissions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html).